# Error while placing order in Softlayer

Tags: json, api, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

We have a made solution for IBM dst team to place order for storage from SoftLayer. We already tested the solution many times, it was working fine. Right now we have got issue while placing order.

I have got error while placing order for both performance & endurance.
The error is

```
"Your order will exceed the maximum number of storage volumes allowed. Please contact Sales." with code "code":"SoftLayer_Exception_Order_LimitReached_Storage_VolumeCount"
```

Can you please tell me how many number of performance or endurance storage can be allowed to order by a user.

Answer (score 0):

There are account limits present. Please, you need to contact Sales team about getting that raised.

The reason for it is so that Sales can help you with capacity planning.